Mildew or mold under window sill?
Can someone tell from this photo if this brown residue is mildew or mold. It's on the wood directly under my window sill and over the radiator.

Mildew is a surface-level fungus that grows on top of wet, hard surfaces. Mold is a fungus that roots deep into softer organic materials like wood that are wet.

OK DR. science...so what are the spots?

These marks are on surface of whatever is coating the wood.  You have a dark dot and then a ring forming around it. Could be from some oily particles or gifts from insects after a good meal. What happens if you wipe it with a liquid cleaner?

I tried scrubbing it with alcohol which lightened it a little. A couple of people I know suggested these are rust stains. There have been bugs coming through my window screen, different types of beetles, but would they leave those kinds of markings? Bed bugs wouldn't hang out by the window, would they? I'm not getting bites and there's no sign of them in my bedding or furniture.

For the past 6 weeks or so there have been many different types of beetles coming through the window screen where they end up on the window sill and then die. The exterminator confirmed they are beetles because they have wings. Could beetles leave excrement like that? The exterminator didn't think the stains were from bugs and neither did the Super in my building. The Super said it was likely rust from trapped moisture and that I should keep an eye on it. I was just looking for another opinion on here.
